# delete user alias with the Admin Directory API java library

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I do not see a method with the java library to delete an alias from a user. Is there a way to do this? I tried using setAliases with a null value.

Comment: In directory API, you can use Users.aliases: delete to delete the alias of a user. Check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the problem earlier.

I have to call Directory.Users.Aliases.Delete:

```
Directory.Users.Aliases requestAliases = service.users().aliases();

Directory.Users.Aliases.Delete deleteAlias = requestAliases.delete(yourId, yourAlias);
deleteAlias.execute();
```